# What is the difference between -generic and -virtual kernels?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, ubuntu-12.04, kernel

I am using XEN server 6.0 on machine and I want to install ubuntu 12.04 64bit. I want to optimize OS for running as VM.

I choose to install from "http://archive.ubuntu.net/ubuntu/" but its showing wide range of kernels:

```
linux-image-extra-3.2.0-23-virtual 
linux-image-extra-virtual 
linux-image-generic 
linux-image-extra-3.2.0-24-virtual
linux-image-3.2.0-25-virtual 
linux-image-3.2.0-23-generic
```

Which kernel is the optimized kernel for running as a VM?
What is the difference between these kernels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe Lucas may be a bit off with his explanation. The virtual kernel comes with a specific set of modules designed to run on common VM setups (vmware, virtualbox, xen, etc.). VM setups have very specific sets of supported "virtual" hardware, and thus do not require, nor are able to make use of a lot of the standard modules. If the virtual kernel lacks a module you need, that's when the virtual-extras comes in. It includes the modules missing from the virtual kernel; installing it adds the missing modules.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC there is no difference between extra-virtual and virtual, virtual just comes with extra drivers that are needed when installing in a virtual environment. These aren't present in the others.

Comment: thanx again Lucas Kauffman :)